# How to display a date as select tag (only day of the week and date of the month)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript or jQuery, I am trying to place a date picker on my website and I am able to place a datepicker with calendar, but I need it without a calendar and as a select box.

[image: check the example image]

Any idea how to do it in javascript or jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a custom control. It will depend on your use case. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Check these solutions they might be helpful http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/ and http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/curdateform2.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably aren't going to be able to modify datepicker to do this (I will gladly concede to anyone proving otherwise), but you can easily add dates to a standard select control.

In this code, I have used the formatDate from the datepicker UI, so you'll need to include jQuery UI, or at least the datepicker component, for it to work.

The following example adds 10 days, starting with the current day to a select element with an ID of "mySelect".

```
$(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = new Date();

    for (x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
        date.setDate(today.getDate() + x);
        textDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('D, dd-M', date);
        $('#mySelect')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", textDate)
            .text(textDate));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi ,thank you .I Did as you specified but i am not getting the output properly, Could you please help with me with a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: In addition to this code the only things you need are links to jQuery (Framework and Extensions in left pane) and jQuery UI (see the External Resources in the left pane), and `<select id='mySelect'>` in the HTML.

Comment: It works now but the output displays the 10 dates with day and some dates are missing in between ,the same happens with the jsfiddle example too.

Comment: @vinoth Sorry--I obviously didn't look closely at the dates it created.  I have updated it to correct it.